# Why is this template defining a set of aliased types matching void?

Tags: c++, templates, using

I'm wrapping the get function of a variant with a templated function returning a type defined in a struct of aliased types. I should be able to enter the aliased type into the template and have the function return a value of that type, but instead, the type is failing to match and returning 'void'. Why is this the case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

struct Type
{
    using String = std::string;
    using Int = int;
};

template<typename T>
using TType = enable_if_t<
    is_same<T, Type::String>::value ||
    is_same<T, Type::Int>::value
>;

template<typename T> TType<T> getValue(variant<Type::String, Type::Int> const& value)
{
    return get<T>(value);
}

int main()
{
    variant<Type::String, Type::Int> value = "";
    cout << getValue<Type::String>(value) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Is there any sneaky trick or other tactical reason that I'm not seeing for using `struct Type` instead of `namespace Type`?

Comment: @user4581301 Now I think about it probably not. In my actual implementation, Type is a member of a class. Since namespaces can't access variables in the class scope, I avoided using one, but it wouldn't actually be an issue in this case I don't think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enable_if_t` takes two parameters.  The second is the type that will be enabled, and is `void` by default.  Change your `TType` declaration to

```
template<typename T>
using TType = enable_if_t<
    is_same<T, Type::String>::value ||
    is_same<T, Type::Int>::value,
    T
>;
```

(adding a `, T` after your condition).

Comment: Ah, that's it, thank you! I'd only ever used enable_if as an anonymous type parameter. This makes a lot of sense.